# Strings not setting in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a javascript project, and I am having trouble displaying an appended string. Right now, I am trying to change Crawler1 and Crawler2 to username that a user input. These usernames are stored in local storage:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left_col">
      <p id="p1">Crawler 1</p>  
    </div>

    <div id="right_col">
      <p id="p2">Crawler 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JS script I am using in order to change the p1 and p2 values to the user names. I am very confused why nothing is appending, because when I use a `window.alert` box, 
`localStorage.getItem("name")` and `localStorage.getItem("name2")` print the expected values.

```
document.forms["game"]["p1"].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
document.forms["game"]["p2"].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name2");
```

does anyone have any idea why the `p1` and `p2` values wouldn't be changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try using...

```
document.querySelector('#left_col p').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
document.querySelector('#right_col p').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
```

...?

Or if you really need to scope the query inside the form

```
const form = document.querySelector('form[name=game]');
form.querySelector('#left_col p').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
form.querySelector('#right_col p').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
```

## [edit] Explanation

Looking your markup, you want to access to a `<p>` inside a `<div id="">`.
`document.querySelector()` allows you to get a `DOMElement` using a `CSS selector`.

The css selector `#left_col p` matches all the `<p>` inside an element with `id="left_col"`.

More on CSS Selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: I haven't, what exactly does this do?

Comment: This worked!! thank you.. can you please explain why I needed to do this??

Answer (score 0):

[Forms returns an `HTMLCollection` of `HTMLFormElements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

You can access the collection with the id of the names and this will return a `HTMLFormElement`. But using `['element-id']` on the `HTMLFormElement` won't do anything.

Instead you can use `querySelector` as @simnutoli has shown or `getElementById` like below.

```
localStorage.setItem('a', 'b');
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('a');
```